# Polymorphism in objective C

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

I guess there is no operator overloading in objective C. Exact function overloading as in C++ is not present.

In what way polymorphism is implemented in objective C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages are handled dynamically, which gives an equivalent to C++ virtual methods.

If the parent class has a message `-doSomething` and a child class re-implements `-doSomething`, regardless of the type of reference you have to the child object, calling `[instance doSomething]` will invoke the child's method.

I'm not sure what operator overloading has to do with polymorphism, but yes, operator overloading does not exist in Objective C.

Comment: Operator overloading is orthogonal to polymorphism.  I'd also add that if you call `doSomething`, the receiver doesn't even have to be a subclass.  It'll just work as long as the instance responds tot he method.

Comment: Is it good programming practice to use this to pass information from super class to child class?